# How to open Bootstrap Modal from a button click in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm quite new to React and Bootstrap. I'm trying to implement a modal dialog on button click. **My modal currently is not displaying** - you can see on the 2nd snippet of code how I'm trying to include the modal using a boolean show variable.

I've seen various libraries which help to do this but I wanted to try understand how to make this work without those libraries first.

**I'm not sure why this modal does not show.**

```
const ModalContent = () => {
    return (
        <div className="modal">
          <div className="modal-dialog">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here. {modalInfo}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

```
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
                <table className="table table-hover">
                    ...
                </table>

                <Pagination itemsCount={filtered.length}
                            pageSize={pageSize}
                            currentPage={currentPage}
                            onPageChange={handlePageChange}/>

            </div>
            {show ? <ModalContent /> : null}
        </div>
```

Comment: how is `show` variable updated /  changed?

Comment: I have a function which toggles the value but for debugging purposes, I've set it to true all the time @Tushar

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, you are missing the button which should toggle the modal.

Page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also setup a custom trigger using with this line of code:

> Call a modal with id myModal with a single line of JavaScript:

```
$('#myModal').modal(options)
```

Options: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options

(Not tested) you could also try to use `Document.getElementById()` to get the element and call modal.

That said, I don't know if it is a good idea to use jQuery when you already use React, but I think you already know that there is an implementation for React Bootstrap already.

Answer (score 0):

2 words, conditional rendering is the best way to do it. Like this:

```
 <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
                <table className="table table-hover">
                    ...
                </table>

                <Pagination itemsCount={filtered.length}
                            pageSize={pageSize}
                            currentPage={currentPage}
                            onPageChange={handlePageChange}/>

            </div>
            {show &&  <ModalContent />}
        </div>
```

the logic behind it is like this , if both sides of & operator are true , they will be rendered , if not, none of them will render, therefore causing the modal to not render at all.